# How to kill my program IMMEDIATELY

Tags: c++

How can I terminate my program (using code) *immediately*.

- I don't want destructors called.
- I don't want any hooks to execute.
- I just want the bare minimum way to kill the program.

(I'm not looking for answers that say this is not kosher. I know it's not.)

EDIT: Looking for Windows and Linux solutions.

EDIT2: I've tried `exit`, `_exit`, `abort`, and `terminate` without success on Windows.

EDIT3: While I don't yet have access to a Linux box, I was able to successfully kill my Windows program with the following code:

```
int pid = _getpid();
char buff[256];
sprintf(buff, "taskkill /pid %d /f", pid);
system(buff);
```

Comment: What's your environment?

Comment: The functions you listed should do the trick. Is there a specific reasons that these are not sufficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just call `_exit()`, available on both [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit) and [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wdz5232.aspx). It won't produce a core-dump like `abort()` will.

**Edit**: If `_exit()` isn't good enough for you, you'll probably have to go platform-specific.

On Windows, you can call [`TerminateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is, as far as I know, the most forceful/immediate method to kill a process exposed by the Windows API (though if there's a more forceful one I'd love to learn about it).

On Linux, raising `SIGKILL` might be better, as [suggested by Jeffery Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035112/how-to-kill-my-program-immediately/28035252#28035252). I actually don't know if `SIGKILL` is more forceful/immediate than `_exit()` or not.

Both of these methods are asynchronous.

Comment: You can change the abort() behaviour by calling _set_abort_behavior http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k089yyh0.aspx

Comment: @Simon: but that still lets the `SIGABRT` handler be called, which I'm guessing the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: @Cornstalks: there is also an `atexit()`.

Comment: @Jongware: `_exit()` (notice the underscore) doesn't call the `atexit()`/`on_exit()` functions.

Comment: @Cornstalks: ooo that's subtle! Thanks, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 7):

On POSIX compliant UNIX systems, [`raise(SIGKILL)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) will do what you want.

---

For Windows, [`TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(),0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx) is what I would look at first. NOTE: This could cause problems for globally shared DLL's.

---

As a final comment, you didn't give any details, but for whatever you are trying to do, you're doing it the wrong way if this is your way out.

Answer (score 3):

Use `_exit()`. This will kill your program immediatly.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the `abort()` function in C, or `std::terminate` in C++.
(`terminate` is also a C function in Visual C++, but it's nonstandard.)

Comment: No, for instance this could trigger a debugger. I suspect there are some more hooks.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 `_Exit` (note: uppercase `E`) is specified as §18.5/3

> **”** The program is terminated without executing destructors for objects of automatic, thread, or
>   static storage duration and without calling functions passed to `atexit()`

If you want possible handlers to execute then you can instead call `std::quick_exit`, which calls registered handlers and then `_Exit`.